# Writing a custom builder that executes external command and python function

Tags: scons

I'm looking to write a custom SCons Builder that:

1. Executes an external command to produce `foo.temp`
2. Then executes a python function to manipulate `foo.temp` and produce the final output file

I've referred to the two following sections, but I'm not sure the correct way to "glue" them together.

- [18.1. Writing Builders That Execute External Commands](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14704984)
- [18.4. Builders That Execute Python Functions](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14732648)

I know that [`Command`](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-user.html#f-Command) accepts a list of actions to take. But how do I properly handle that intermediate file? Ideally the intermediate file would be invisible to the user -- the entire Builder would appear to operate atomically.

---

Here's what I've come up with that seems to be working. However the `.bin` file isn't being deleted automatically.

```python
from SCons.Action import Action
from SCons.Util import is_List
from SCons.Script import Delete

_objcopy_builder = Builder(
        action = 'objcopy -O binary $SOURCE $TARGET',
        suffix = '.bin',
        single_source = 1
        )

def _add_header(target, source, env):
    source = str(source[0])
    target = str(target[0])

    with open(source, 'rb') as src:
        with open(target, 'wn') as tgt:
            tgt.write('MODULE\x00\x00')
            tgt.write(src.read())
    return 0

_addheader_builder = Builder(
        action = _add_header,
        single_source = 1
        )

def Elf2Mod(env, target, source, *args, **kw):
    def check_one(x, what):
        if not is_List(x):
            x = [x]
        if len(x) != 1:
            raise StopError('Only one {0} allowed'.format(what))
        return x
    target = check_one(target, 'target')
    source = check_one(source, 'source')

    # objcopy a binary file
    binfile = _objcopy_builder.__call__(env, source=source, **kw)

    # write the module header
    _addheader_builder.__call__(env, target=target, source=binfile, **kw)

    # delete the intermediate binary file
    # TODO: Not working
    Delete(binfile)

    return target

def generate(env):
    """Add Builders and construction variables to the Environment."""
    env.AddMethod(Elf2Mod, 'Elf2Mod')
    print 'Added Elf2Mod to env {0}'.format(env)

def exists(env):
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

This can indeed be done with the [Command builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-user.html#f-Command), by specifying a list of actions, as follows:

```
Command('foo.temp', 'foo.in',
        ['your_external_action',
         your_python_function])
```

Notice that `foo.in` is the source, and you should name it accordingly. But if `foo.temp` is internal as you mention, then this approach probably isnt the best approach.

Another way, which I feel is much more flexible, would be to use [Custom Builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-writing) with a [Generator](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14742400) and/or [Emitter](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14754152).

The `Generator` is a Python function where you do the actual work, which in your case would be calling the external command, and also call the Python function.

An `Emitter` allows you to have a fine-tuned control over the sources and targets. I used a `Builder` with a `Emitter` (and `Generator`) once to do C++ and Java code-generation with Thrift input IDL files. I had to read and process the Thrift input file to know exactly what files would be code-generated (which are the actual targets), and the `Emitter` is the best/only way to do something like this. If your particular use-case isnt so complicated, you can skip the `Emitter` and just list your sources/targets in the call to the builder. But if you want `foo.temp` to be transparent to the end-user, then you'll need an Emitter.

When using a Custom Builder with a Generator and Emitter, the Emitter will be called every time by SCons to calculate the sources and dependencies to know if the Generator needs to be called. The Generator will only be called if one of the targets is considered older with respect to the sources.

There are numerous examples showing how to use a Generator and Emitter in a Custom Builder, so I wont list the code here, but let me know if you need help with the syntax, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've written a psuedo-builder (see my edit) that seems to be working. But I'm not sure if it is correct. Also the original ELF file would also be needed in the generation of the different header.

Comment: I'm realizing that the simpler solution might be to relax the "invisible intermediate file" requirement, and just produce a .bin as part of the build. Then use the .elf and .bin to produce the custom module.

Comment: Or, since the operation is logically .elf -> .module, should an Emitter be used to indicate that a .bin file is a side-effect?